# html : navigation style change on hover

Tags: javascript, css, html, menu, hover

this is a part of a code in which i'm trying to change the menu item color when hover on a different div. I can modify the background color but not the actual text color.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<style type="text/css">
.navigation li a { color: grey;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul  class="navigation" id="nav">
<li id="a" onmouseover="chbg('red')" onmouseout="chbg('black')"><a href="#abt">ABOUT </a></li>
<li id="b" onmouseover="chbg1('red')" onmouseout="chbg1('white')"><a href="#sequence">CONTENT</a></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
function chbg(color) {
    document.getElementById('b').style.Color = color;
}
function chbg1(color) {
    document.getElementById('a').style.backgroundColor = color;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Need help in solving this issue.
Thanks

Comment: You are much better off using CSS `:hover` to achieve this.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're trying to do this with Javascript?

Comment: yeah.. but this is just a sample code and what i actually want is when a particular part of my page is hovered i want the menu styling to change. to show that the part refers to that particular menu section. I'm not sure if it actually makes sense

Answer (score 1):

You are applying color to the `li` but the `a` is already getting `color: gray;` from the CSS.

As mentioned in the comment you would be much better off handling stuff like this with CSS and not JavaScript.

```
a {
  color: gray;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: red;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

EDIT: It also seems like you misspelled `gray`. In CSS the american spelling is used. This is part of why I use hex-values in stead.

Comment: Hey.. thanks for your comment but the style swapping does not happen here.. i'm new to this..

Comment: What do you mean "style swapping"? Are you not trying to achive something linke [this](http://jsfiddle.net/T74VD/)?

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS its much easier

```
.navigation #a {
  background:black;
}

.navigation #b {
  background:white;
}

.navigation li:hover {
  background:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/PBJ8R/)**</kbd>

```
#a {
    background-color: black;
}
#b {
    background-color: white;
}
#b:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
#a:hover > a {
    color: green;
}
#b:hover > a {
    color: yellow;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="navigation" id="nav">
    <li id="a"><a href="#abt">ABOUT </a>
    </li>
    <li id="b"><a href="#sequence">CONTENT</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```